# Pyspark/Python: Shuffle rows/records in a few columns grouped by same type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to shuffle three columns(function_txt, item_txt and value_txt) on pyspark based on the similar vehicle_id and same diag_sid. Eg:
Input:

| diag_sid | vehicle_id | source | function_txt | item_txt | value_txt | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1711364453938960795 | W1KAH0FB1PF092903 | A | Bordnetzdaten_EZS222 | 22105E | 1A 00 18 CA 05 7A... | 2024-03-25 |
| 1711364453938960795 | W1KAH0FB1PF092903 | A | Bordnetzdaten_EZS223 | 221058 | 01 E4 FD E8 FD E0... | 2024-03-25 |

So far, I tried df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index)), but this is just re-ordering the rows without shuffling the data within the cells.

Is there any method in pyspark which can shuffle only some columns within the same group of records(here by diag_sid and vehicle_id)?

Expected output:

| diag_sid | vehicle_id | source | function_txt | item_txt | value_txt | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1711364453938960795 | W1KAH0FB1PF092903 | A | Bordnetzdaten_EZS223 | 221058 | 01 E4 FD E8 FD E0... | 2024-03-25 |
| 1711364453938960795 | W1KAH0FB1PF092903 | A | Bordnetzdaten_EZS222 | 22105E | 1A 00 18 CA 05 7A... | 2024-03-25 |

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are doing this. But here's a recipe.

First combine all the columns that you want to be shuffled into a struct ALONG with a random integer.

Then, create a Window spec where you partition over the columns which should remain same and order by the struct's random integer.

Then unpack the struct to retrieve your original columns.
Following is an example.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data = [
    ("1711364453938960795", "W1KAH0FB1PF092903", "A", "Bordnetzdaten_EZS222", "22105E", "1A 00 18 CA 05 7A", "2024-03-25"),
    ("1711364453938960795", "W1KAH0FB1PF092903", "A", "Bordnetzdaten_EZS223", "221058", "01 E4 FD E8 FD E0", "2024-03-25")
]

schema = ["diag_sid", "vehicle_id", "source", "function_txt", "item_txt", "value_txt", "date"]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

df = df.withColumn("rand_int", F.expr("cast(floor(rand() * 1000) as int)"))

df = df.withColumn("info", F.struct( "rand_int", "source", "function_txt", "item_txt", "value_txt", "date")).drop("source", "function_txt", "item_txt", "value_txt", "date", "rand_int")
df.show(truncate=False)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("diag_sid", "vehicle_id").orderBy("info.rand_int")

df = df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+-------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+----------+
|diag_sid           |vehicle_id       |source|function_txt        |item_txt|value_txt        |date      |
+-------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+----------+
|1711364453938960795|W1KAH0FB1PF092903|A     |Bordnetzdaten_EZS222|22105E  |1A 00 18 CA 05 7A|2024-03-25|
|1711364453938960795|W1KAH0FB1PF092903|A     |Bordnetzdaten_EZS223|221058  |01 E4 FD E8 FD E0|2024-03-25|
+-------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+----------+

+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|diag_sid           |vehicle_id       |info                                                                 |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1711364453938960795|W1KAH0FB1PF092903|{561, A, Bordnetzdaten_EZS222, 22105E, 1A 00 18 CA 05 7A, 2024-03-25}|
|1711364453938960795|W1KAH0FB1PF092903|{162, A, Bordnetzdaten_EZS223, 221058, 01 E4 FD E8 FD E0, 2024-03-25}|
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|diag_sid           |vehicle_id       |info                                                                 |row_num|
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|1711364453938960795|W1KAH0FB1PF092903|{162, A, Bordnetzdaten_EZS223, 221058, 01 E4 FD E8 FD E0, 2024-03-25}|1      |
|1711364453938960795|W1KAH0FB1PF092903|{561, A, Bordnetzdaten_EZS222, 22105E, 1A 00 18 CA 05 7A, 2024-03-25}|2      |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! This works! I admit the requirement is weird since it is what is given by the business